# Navigation system goes a little weird when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am having a little problem with the navigation list items going a little below the top-bar when I resize the browser. When I remove the image it seems to be working perfectly fine on all screen resolutions but inserting the logo has had an affect on this. Is there any way I can solve this. Can't seem to find out what the problem is.

HTML:

```
<!-- HEADER START -->
 <div id="header">
 <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">

  <li class="name">
    <h1>
  <a href="index.html"><img src="img/flogo.svg" class="logo" alt="Logo">  
    Sharp <span>Media  </span>          
      </a>
    </h1>
   </li>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="index.html"><span>menu</span></a></li>
</ul>

<section class="top-bar-section">

  <ul class="right">
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <ul class="dropdown">

          </ul>
        </li>

    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQs</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown">
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      <ul class="dropdown">

        <li class="divider"></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
     </ul>
   </section>
   </nav>
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS? or create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6L1nppp9/

Comment: Since its a foundation framework I have not inserted the foundation CSS its way too much